# is my compass map wrong?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

```
Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "    grey": expected ")", was ": ("
        on line 42 of D:/treehouse(2015)/modular_sass/1-Getting_Modular_with_Mixins_and_Functions/video-5/start/scss/_config.scss
        from line 1 of D:/treehouse(2015)/modular_sass/1-Getting_Modular_with_Mixins_and_Functions/video-5/start/scss/application.scss
```

i dont know why iam getting this error while compiling the `$paletts` color map 
i also have compass installed...
my map:

```
    $paletts: (
    grey: (
        xx-light: lighten($grey, 43%);
        x-light : lighten($grey, 35%);
        light   : lighten($grey, 12%);
        base    : $grey;
        dark    : darken($grey, 8%);
        x-dark  : darken($grey, 16%);

    ),


     black: (
        light   : lighten($black, 12%);
        base    : $black;
        dark    : darken($black, 8%);  
    ),
);
```

i'm also getting the following error when i try to watch my project via compass. does anyone know what's happening???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in sass maps key-value pairs are separated by commas not semi-colon

Comment: ya, i just debugged it out thnx anyway.

Answer (score 0):

beware, use `,` instead of `;` in sass-maps.i did the same thing as i was in javascript dilemma. 
this is the correct map:

```
$palettes: (
 grey: (
        xx-light: lighten($grey,43%),
        x-light : lighten($grey,35%),
        light   : lighten($grey,12%),
        base    : $grey,
        dark    : darken($grey,8%),
        x-dark  : darken($grey,16%),

    ),


     black: (
        light   : lighten($black,12%),
        base    : $black,
        dark    : darken($black,8%),
    ),
);
```